# jquery .click() function on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, mobile

I have this function:

```
function inizia(){
    $( ".con-playpause" ).click();
    cambia();
};
```

When I click on a button it calls the function `inizia()` and simulate a click on another button. This works on desktop, but I have problems on mobile! It executes the function `cambia()` but doesn't simulate the click.

Comment: how many objects does the `.con-playpause` selector reference?  If it's just one, you might try changing the selector to the ID of the object instead.

Comment: it reference to two buttons

Comment: I'd try just referencing one of those objects by its ID to see if that makes a difference.  If it does, you could just chain them in the selector list.  Mobile is a bit funky when it comes to jQuery selectors...

Comment: it was a problem of Ids. Thanks for help!

Comment: no prob, I'll put that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how many objects does the .con-playpause selector reference? If it's just one, you might try changing the selector to the ID of the object instead

I'd try just referencing one of those objects by its ID to see if that makes a difference. If it does, you could just chain them in the selector list. Mobile is a bit funky when it comes to jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you bound the .con-playpause selector to a behavior before calling the .click() function?
Like that, for example:

```
$('.con-playpause').on("click", function() {
    //do something here
});
```

Comment: Not necessarily. I had the same kind of issue, I realized things have to be more explicit with mobile sometimes. The element with class con-playpause could be an anchor link for instance.

Answer (score 0):

**Try putting the `cambia()` inside the click function:**

```
function inizia(){
    $( ".con-playpause" ).click(function() {
     cambia();
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use it in javascript and add an id to the button element, like this:

```
function inizia(){
    document.getElementById("con-playpause").click();
    cambia();
};
```

and in your html:

```
<button type="button" id="con-playpause">Click Me!</button>
```